# Newly created Facet is not showing in Content Search view

Tags: content-search, search-facet

I created a facet as per the documentation: https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/92/sitecore-experience-manager/facets.html

In the "Field Name" field I tried the field name as in the item's template and also as in the Solr index. Neither worked.

How do I make it show up in the Sitecore Content Search? Are there any additional settings I have to do?

[image]

Comment: did you rebuild the indexes after you made the changes?

Comment: @VladIobagiu yep. Multiple times. No updates

Comment: Please make sure the format of `Field Name` is correct - it should be similar to Solr field name (lowercase and with underscores instead of spaces) but without the field type suffix. For example, if Sitecore field is called "Title", you should specify `title` instead of `title_t`. You can also check Search.log for any error or info messages - usually there is a log message if something is wrong with a facet.

Comment: @AnnaGevel Actually, that worked. I had to remove the suffix ( + index rebuild ). Thank you.

Comment: @iusmar that's great, I'm glad you solved the problem. I've added this as an answer too so that other people can easily find it in future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please make sure the format of `Field Name` is correct - it should be similar to Solr field name (lowercase and with underscores instead of spaces) but without the field type suffix.

For example, if a text field is called "Title" in Sitecore, you should specify `title` instead of `title_t`.

You can also check Search.log for any error or info messages - usually there is a log message if something is wrong with a facet.